# JSON keeps both old and new list, While List keeps new one

Tags: java, json, list

I'm having problem with my JSON, stuff works perfectly in my List only my JSON Problem, which makes my List copy from JSON when application reset.

So I want to remove old record from JSON by editing old, not creating new one which keeps 2 files.

This is my editing List Code:

```
Supplier TempSupplier = new Supplier();
            TempSupplier.setmSupplierID(ItemFile.CurSupplierList.get(CurrentSupplierIndex).getmSupplierID());
            TempSupplier.setmSupplierName(SupplierNameTextField.getText());
            TempSupplier.setmSupplierDescription(SupplierDescriptionTextArea.getText());
            TempSupplier.setmDate(ItemFile.CurSupplierList.get(CurrentSupplierIndex).getmDate());
            TempSupplier.setmSalesManagerID(ItemFile.CurSupplierList.get(CurrentSupplierIndex).getmSalesManagerID());
```

Basically Just create new temporary object with edited information, and In the I set it to the previous index, so I did not add new list, just replace.

```
ItemFile.CurSupplierList.set(CurrentSupplierIndex, TempSupplier);
```

After Done I start my JSON with this:

```
for (int CurSupplier = 0; CurSupplier < CurSupplierList.size(); CurSupplier++) {
    JSONObject SupplierObj = new JSONObject();

    SupplierObj.put("Status", ItemType);
    SupplierObj.put("SupplierID", CurSupplierList.get(CurSupplier).getmSupplierID());
    SupplierObj.put("Name", CurSupplierList.get(CurSupplier).getmSupplierName());
    SupplierObj.put("Description", CurSupplierList.get(CurSupplier).getmSupplierDescription());
    SupplierObj.put("Date", CurSupplierList.get(CurSupplier).getmDate());
    SupplierObj.put("SalesManagerID", CurSupplierList.get(CurSupplier).getmSalesManagerID());
    ItemListArray.put(SupplierObj);
    WriteToFile();
}
```

So the conclusion problem occurs in JSON, which reads both list after edited and in fact Only One List is founded on my ArrayList, but JSON reads two, just appends it.

Comment: declare JSON object at class level

Comment: I have moved JSON Object outside of the loop, still the same problem

Comment: but still json writes twice ??